# Moving selection to next list item in html using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple list in a html page. using jquery how to find next item which is outside current list.
I have used Jquery for selecting next item, but it is not working in multiple list.
[SampleFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn0s21cL/)

Please find the code which used to move next

```
   function NextDataEntryLoad() {
var li = $('li.highlight').closest('li').next('li');
//var nextli = $('li.highlight').parent().parent().next('li').children().first('li');
li.trigger('click')}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Give class to parent li 'menuContainer' and then check if the last li is clicked then find parent and then next parent with class to trigger click on first li.

```js
    function LastDataEntryLoad() {
        $('ul.nested li:last').trigger('click')
    }
    function FirstDataEntryLoad() {
        $('ul.nested li:first').trigger('click')
    }
    function LoadDataEntryEdit(EntityID, BatchNo, BatchSlNo, el) {
        $('.nestedli').removeClass('highlight');
        $(el).parent().addClass('active');
        $(el).addClass('highlight');
    }
        function NextDataEntryLoad() {
        debugger;
        //var li = $('li.highlight').parent().children().closest('li').next('li')[0];
        //var li = $('li.highlight').closest('li').next('li');
        //li.trigger('click')
        var li = $('li.highlight').closest('li').next('li');
    
    // we check if it's last element
    if ($('li.highlight').is(":last-child")) {
      console.log('last one');
      $('li.highlight').parents('.menuContainer').next('.menuContainer').find('.nestedli:first-child').trigger('click');
    }
    
        //var nextli = $('li.highlight').parent().parent().next('li').children().first('li');
        li.trigger('click')
    }
    function PreviousDataEntryLoad() {
        debugger;
        var li = $('li.highlight').closest('li').prev('li');
        li.trigger('click')
    }
```

```css
    .highlight {
        background-color: cyan;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="FirstDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">First</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="PreviousDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="NextDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="LastDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
<li class="menuContainer">
    <span class="caret">22/06/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested active">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">101</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">102</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10006', '3',this)">
            <a href="#">103</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10007', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">101</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10007', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">102</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10009', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">103</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', 'QW123', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">136</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli highlight" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', 'QW129', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">136</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menuContainer">
    <span class="caret caret-down">01/07/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested active">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">104</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">104</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menuContainer">
    <span class="caret">02/07/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">105</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">105</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menuContainer">
    <span class="caret">10/07/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested active">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '3',this)">
            <a href="#">106</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '3',this)">
            <a href="#">106</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change how you handle the highlighted data. it's better to let javascript handle it than relying on html tags.
Here is an example:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("nestedli");
var currentIndex = 0;

const NextDataEntryLoad = ()=> {
if(currentIndex >= items.length -1) return;
currentIndex++;
refresh()
}
const PreviousDataEntryLoad = ()=> {
if(currentIndex === 0 ) return;
currentIndex--;
refresh()
}



const refresh = ()=> {
Object.keys(items).forEach((key,i)=> {
const li = items[key];
if(i ===currentIndex) {
li.classList.add("highlight");
} else {
li.classList.remove("highlight")
}
})
}

const FirstDataEntryLoad = ()=> {
currentIndex = 0;
refresh()
}
const LastDataEntryLoad = ()=> {
currentIndex = items.length -1;
refresh()

}


const LoadDataEntryEdit = ()=>{}

refresh()
```

```css
    .highlight {
        background-color: cyan;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="FirstDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">First</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="PreviousDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="NextDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" onclick="LastDataEntryLoad()">
                                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
<li>
    <span class="caret">22/06/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested active">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">101</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">102</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10006', '3',this)">
            <a href="#">103</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10007', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">101</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10007', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">102</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10009', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">103</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', 'QW123', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">136</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', 'QW129', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">136</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="caret caret-down">01/07/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested active">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">104</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">104</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="caret">02/07/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">105</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '2',this)">
            <a href="#">105</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="caret">10/07/2020</span>
    <ul class="nested active">
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '3',this)">
            <a href="#">106</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '3',this)">
            <a href="#">106</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this without changing HTML code :

```js
function LastDataEntryLoad() {
  $('ul.nested li:last').trigger('click')
}

function FirstDataEntryLoad() {
  $('ul.nested li:first').trigger('click')
}

function LoadDataEntryEdit(EntityID, BatchNo, BatchSlNo, el) {
  $('.nestedli').removeClass('highlight');
  $(el).parent().addClass('active');
  $(el).addClass('highlight');
}

function NextDataEntryLoad() {
  let li = $('.highlight');
  let highlight = li.next();
  if(highlight.index() < 0){
    let nextList = li.closest('ul').parent();
    if(!nextList.is($('.nestedli:last'))){
      highlight = nextList.next().find('ul li:first-child');
    }
  }
  highlight.trigger('click')
}

function PreviousDataEntryLoad() {
  let li = $('.highlight');
  let highlight = li.prev();
  if(highlight.index() < 0){
    let prevList = li.closest('ul').parent();
    if(!prevList.is($('.pagination').next())){
      highlight = prevList.prev().find('ul li:last-child');
    }
  }
  highlight.trigger('click');
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: cyan;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item" onclick="FirstDataEntryLoad()">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">First</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" onclick="PreviousDataEntryLoad()">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" onclick="NextDataEntryLoad()">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" onclick="LastDataEntryLoad()">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<li>
  <span class="caret">22/06/2020</span>
  <ul class="nested active">
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">101</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '2',this)">
      <a href="#">102</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10006', '3',this)">
      <a href="#">103</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10007', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">101</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10007', '2',this)">
      <a href="#">102</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10009', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">103</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', 'QW123', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">136</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli highlight" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', 'QW129', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">136</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="caret caret-down">01/07/2020</span>
  <ul class="nested active">
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">104</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '1',this)">
      <a href="#">104</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="caret">02/07/2020</span>
  <ul class="nested">
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '2',this)">
      <a href="#">105</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '2',this)">
      <a href="#">105</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="caret">10/07/2020</span>
  <ul class="nested active">
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10008', '3',this)">
      <a href="#">106</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10002', '3',this)">
      <a href="#">106</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution would be to create an attribute for all the list-items of the different lists, probably containg a number iterator number as value, and use that to identify the items you click or want to select.

Something like:

```
    <li>
     <span class="caret">22/06/2020</span>
     <ul class="nested active">
        <li LIST-ITEM='1' class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '1',this)">
            <a href="#">101</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
    <li>
    <li>
      <span class="caret">22/06/2020</span>
        <ul class="nested active">
            <li LIST-ITEM='2' class="nestedli" onclick="LoadDataEntryEdit('1', '10001', '1',this)">
                <a href="#">101</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <li>
```